# Programmatically (C#) set date field to blank in 2010

Tags: 2010, development, date-time

I have tried setting my date field to an empty string ("") and setting it to "01/01/0001". 
Both returned the error "String is not formatted as date time". I have several thousand items across a few subsites which mistakenly received some December date, and I'd like those to be set to empty.

Workflows have proven to take too long for this process, and I already have a C# utility written to update all fields that I specify (e.g., "set "Modified By" on all items with ID > 500 to [My Name]"), but I cannot seem to find a way set a date field back to empty.

Comment: Can you share your code? Try setting the date to null instead of an empty string.

Comment: It's a part of a longer utility. I set date fields in the following format:  `
                                item["Modified"] = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001");

Comment: Try `item["Modified"] = null;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `item["Modified"] = null;`

That should make the Date/Time field empty.